# Problem with processing FFMPEG video , the output video is totally black in first 3 seconds

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg

I want to make a slideshow by using concat demuxer like this link:
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Slideshow

Here is the textfile preinputFiles.txt:

```
file 'path a'
duration 2
file 'path b'
duration 2
file 'path c'
duration 2
file 'path c'
```

and my command array is:

```
String[] cmd = new String[]{
            "-f","concat","-i",
            textFile,
            "-vsync", "vfr", "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p",
            dest.getAbsolutePath()};
```

the video has 3 seconds that it is totally black and run from 3s to 9s even the gallery shows that it is a 6 seconds long video .

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is the actual duration of `path a` and `path b`?

Comment: both of 3 paths is 2 seconds. The slideshow has 3 images and it's totally 6 seconds

Comment: Show output of `ffmpeg -i "path a" -i "path b" -i "path c"`

Comment: i thought of that way too , but the output was same>